# Movie about a strange man in a jail-cell who shoots himself in the mouth

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember a scene of a film I saw in the 1990s- early 2000. I know i was probably was too young to watch that.

So the scene is in a bright room with jail-bars in the back. A man was there, a very strange man, with long and dirty dark hair. I don't know how he got a gun but he shot himself in the mouth. There was other people in the room talking about the strange man.

I seem to remember something about a golden tooth, a car on fire with one or more people inside and a girl with strange drawing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

4 key parts of your description fit in with *[The Pledge](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0237572/)* (2001). Directed by Sean Penn and starring Jack Nicholson.

**Man in jail shot himself in the mouth.**

A suspect (Benicio Del Toro) grabs a gun and shoots himself in the head (through the mouth). He has long, dark hair.

[image: Shot in mouth]

**Golden tooth**

He has a gold tooth.
[image: gold tooth]

It gets a bit gory. The tooth is embedded in the wall and gets extracted by Jack Nicholson.
[image: tooth]

**Girl with strange drawing**

A child's drawing is part of the evidence.
[image: drawing]

**Car on fire**

This happens near the end.
[image: car on fire]